# CSS keyframes Animation stalls ajax success call if scroll wheel is spammed

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, reactjs

I have an **AJAX** query that usually takes about *200ms* to perform. While waiting for the result, I play a little animation of a spinning wheel.

The animation is entirely done with CSS:

```
.glyphicon.spinning {
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

However, I found out that if between the query and the result, I constantly spam the scolling (moving the scroll wheel even if there is no scrollbar on the screen), the success function of the ajax won't be called until after I stop scrolling. This happens on Chrome but not on Firefox, which makes me confident it's not due to my code.

When I use the profiler from the chrome debug tools, it shows this: (`queryTimer` shows the time between the AJAX query and the onSuccess call)

[image: Google Chrome profiler]
So I did three tests:

- Spam + Animation = stalling until spam is stopped
- Spam + no Animation = 200ms
- No spam + Animation = 200ms

Any idea how to stop this Animation from stalling the rest of my code?

Don't know if it is linked, but I am using **ReactJS** for the front end.

EDIT1:
If I change the animation from infinite to let's say '3', the stalling will stop after the animation is done, even if I keep spamming. And as of before, if I don't spam, the animation will be interrupted instead of stalling my code.